# ng serve errors on node modules with apollo client

Tags: typescript, graphql, angular7, apollo-client

hello we have upgraded angular 6 to 7.2 and have installed graphql. When trying to run ng serve we are getting multiple errors with apollo client for the node modules.

> ERROR in node_modules/@apollo/client/core/types.d.ts(38,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
> node_modules/@apollo/client/core/types.d.ts(38,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Observable.d.ts(3,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
> node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Observable.d.ts(3,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
> node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Observable.d.ts(3,61): error TS1109: Expression expected.
> node_modules/graphql-tag/lib/index.d.ts(2,57): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> node_modules/graphql-tag/lib/index.d.ts(2,63): error TS1005: ',' expected.
> node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts(6,87): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected.
> node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts(7,49): error TS1005: ']' expected.
> node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts(7,51): error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.
> node_modules/ts-invariant/lib/invariant.d.ts(7,83): error TS1005: ';' expected.

and our package json looks like -->

```
{

  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "graphql-codegen": "npx graphql-codegen"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.0.0",
    "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer": "^14.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/angular": "^1.8.3",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.9.0",
    "angular-image-slider": "0.0.8",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "apollo-angular": "^2.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "contentful": "^7.15.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "marked": "^0.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.9",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.5.2",
    "ngx-markdown": "^8.2.2",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.4.7",
    "ngx-text-overflow-clamp": "0.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.2.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.10.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.3.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.4.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular": "^3.3.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

please can anyone help on this how to get rid of these errors when running our app.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading typescript can solve you problem.